# Stringify returning Object object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following in my .js file

```
api.rooms = class {
    static get url() {
    return "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/rooms/";
  }

  static getRooms() {
       return $.ajax({
       url: api.rooms.url,
       method: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       timeout: api.timeout,
       }).then(function(data) {
           return data.rooms.map(item => item.name)[0]; //Works OK!
        });   
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").text(api.rooms.getRooms().done(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Request failed: jqXHR.status=" + jqXHR.status + ",                 
       textStatus=" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
    }))
});
```

Now getRooms() seems to be working fine and when I test my whole code the console prints what it is supposed to print. But I want to take what's printed in the console and instead of printing it there replacing the text in my 'h3' element with 'title' id with that one. **Turns out that my element with id 'title' and tag 'h3' ends up having the text [object Object] instead of the one I want.**
How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: The default string representation of an object is `"[object Object]"`. You have to access the property that you want to show.

Comment: you are talking about this statement `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` you wan to be printed in the html

Comment: the problem is, that `api.rooms.getRooms().done(....` returns a jQuery **object** - not the data you are expecting ... so it's just like running `$("#title").text({})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you hit upon one of the most interesting things about Javascript: callback functions! Unfortunately, as you discovered, the actual return value of `api.rooms.getRooms().done` (or actually, `.done().fail`) is not so useful. Probably you meant:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    api.rooms.getRooms().done(function(data) {
        var rooms = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(rooms);
        $("#title").text(rooms); // <<< sets the DOM element <<<
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Request failed: jqXHR.status=" + jqXHR.status + ",                 
       textStatus=" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
    });
});
```

## What's going on

When `api.getRooms().done()` returns, chances are that it actually hasn't made the network request yet! What it did is make an agreement that it will call this function if the data comes back successfully:

```
function(data) {
    var rooms = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(rooms);
    $("#title").text(rooms); // <<< sets the DOM element <<<
}
```

This is very common style in JS. Network requests take a long time, and we might want to do other things while we wait for a request to finish. The solution is to pass in a `function(data)` which will tell JS what to do once the `data` is ready. The actual return value of these functions isn't used and doesn't matter.<sup>1</sup>

This is part of asynchronous programming: instead of using `return rooms;` at the end of the `callback` function, we call another function like `$("#title").text(rooms);` to actually do something once the data comes back.

## Going deeper

For more examples of continuation passing style (which I used here), and info about callback hell and ways to avoid it, these articles might point you in new directions to advance your learning:

- [Understanding JavaScript Callbacks](https://closebrace.com/tutorials/2017-01-17/understanding-javascript-callbacks)
- [Callbacks vs Promises vs RxJS vs async/await](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-rxjs-vs-async-awaits/)

---

<sup>1</sup> The one place where the return value is used is as a convenient place to hang the `.done()` and `.fail()` calls. That's the `[object Object]` you are seeing. Once you have assigned the done and fail callbacks, you will never need that object again.

Theoretically speaking, that object is not an essential part of continuation passing style, and not every library works this way. It just lets you chain the `.done()` and the `.fail()` calls (which also return that object, for chaining) and makes your code look pretty. The designer could also have made the done and fail callbacks arguments to the request, which is algebraically simpler, but harder to read in practice:

```
api.rooms.getRooms(function done(data) {...}, function fail(...) {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell what property of the object you want printed out. Stringify converst the contents of the object to a string. So if you want your title property then do something like.

```
$('#my_h3').text( data.title );
```

Comment: what is `#my_h3`?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, thats and id selector. eg: <h3 id="my_h3">...</h3>

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
api.rooms.getRooms().done(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Request failed: jqXHR.status=" + jqXHR.status + ",                 
   textStatus=" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
})
```

is a *jQuery **object***

So, your code is equivalent to

```
$("#title").text({})
```

Any object here will result in #title content being `[object Object]`

Asynchrony can not be shortcut ... you'll need to do something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    api.rooms.getRooms().done(function(data) {
        $("#title").text(JSON.stringify(data));
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Request failed: jqXHR.status=" + jqXHR.status + ",                 
       textStatus=" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
    }))
});
```

instead